# Add delegate to Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Problem: I want to write the same message to a textbox control that I am writing to a log file.

I have a windows form (Form1.cs) that calls a crosscutting class of static methods. In each of the crosscutting methods, they call WriteLogEntry to update a log file of what they are doing. I'd like to send back an event to Form1 so I can write the same log message to a control on the form.

I have looked at events but do not understand enough to make sense of the examples and have not found a simple enough example to do what I want. Can someone show me a simiple example of how to add an event to my code to accomplish this?

```
namespace MainForm
{
    public delegate void MyDel(string str);

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public event MyDel MyEvent;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyEvent += new MyDel(WriteSomething);

            Crosscutting.DoSomething();
        }

        public void WriteSomething(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }

    //Crosscutting.cs

    public class Crosscutting
    {
        private static void WriteLogEntry(string message)
        {
             // Code to write message to log file.
        }

        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            WriteSomething obj = new WriteSomething();

            // Code to do something.

            WriteLogEntry("I'm doing something");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples of how to write `Events as well as Delegates` this is not the forum to be asking how to do something that you could have easily googled and found 1000's of examples

Comment: You should at least try to add event to your code. When you will get an error or some other kind of unexpected result, then return and ask for help with your problem. Your current question do not have any problem to be solved

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+event+log+entry&oq=C%23+Eventlog+en&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j69i58j0l4.9567j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @methodMan Well, I did say that I cannot find an example that fit my needs that I could understand.

Comment: out of `806,000` Google Results..? I find that quite hard to believe..

Comment: @MethodMan maybe I did not write clear enough because the link you added shows how to write to the event log. I'm trying to figure out subscribing from a class to a windows form event.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I've made updates on adding an event to a form. I have no idea how to subscribe to it from within the Crosssutting class.

Comment: @Wannabe same way as you did with `WriteSomething` - you should attach some method of Crosscutting which have appropriate signature. E.g. `MyEvent += Crosscutting.WriteLogEntry`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy The error I get is: The type or namespace name 'WriteSomething' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? Which I know is not right but do not know how to fix it.

Comment: @Wannabe you have piece of strange code in `DoSomething()` method: `WriteSomething obj = new WriteSomething();` - that should be removed.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy are you saying I have it backwards and the Crosscutting should have the event, not the form?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy "piece of strange code" that is why I did not attempt to write anything when I first asked the question...I just do not understand it yet.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a great place to get help. Thanks to sergeyBerezovdkiy for trying to help. @ModernMan, this is a place to learn and I said I had no clue about what to do...thanks for berating me for not knowing something and not able to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not being able to figure out how to use a delegate to get back to the form, I tried another way. By creating an instance of Form1 on "MyClass", I was able to use a public method to write back to the form. Not the way I wanted, but it is a way to get it done for now. If anyone can explain how to do this a better way, please do so.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string message = string.Empty;

    public static Form1 form;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        form = this;
    }

    public void UpdateTextBox(string message)
    {
        textBox1.Text += message + Environment.NewLine;

        this.Update();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();

        myClass.DoSomething();
    }
}


public class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Log("I did something");
    }

    private void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        Form1.form.UpdateTextBox(message);
    }
}
```